# Spring initialize bean with hostname

Tags: spring, initialization

I need to fill a property of a bean with the current hostname just like the call returns it:
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()

It should be something like so:

`<bean id="hostname"  value="InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()" />`

`<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">`

`<property name="schedulerName" ref="hostname" />`

`</bean>`

Comment: Do you have to configure your bean with xml, or are you allowed to use configuration with java annotations ? In the second case, it would be easier to do what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done somewhat simply with xml, as detailed in [sections 3.3.2.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) and [3.3.2.3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method) of the Spring documentation.

In summary, section 3.3.2.2 suggests a method of invoking a `static` method of a class.  This can be done as so:

```
<bean id="myBean"
  class="com.foo.MyClass"
  factory-method="myStaticMethod"/>
```

This will create a bean in the `ApplicationContext` with a name of `myBean`, which is populated by the returned object from an invokation of `MyClass.myStaticMethod()`.

But this is only halfway there, as we only have the result of the `static` method (the first call in your case).

Section 3.3.2.3 details how to invoke a non-static method of a bean that lives in the `ApplicationContext` already.  It can be done as so:

```
<bean id="myOtherBean"
  factory-bean="myBean"
  factory-method="myNonStaticMethod"/>
```

This will create a bean in the `ApplicationContext` with a name of `myOtherBean`, which is populated by the returned object from an invokation of `myBean.myNonStaticMethod()`, where `myBean` is the bean pulled from the `ApplicationContext`.

When put together, you should be able to achieve what you are after.

```
<bean id="localhostInetAddress"
  class="java.net.InetAddress"
  factory-method="getLocalHost"/>

<bean id="hostname"
  factory-bean="localhostInetAddress"
  factory-method="getHostName"/>
```

Of course the easier way to do this is with [Java Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java).

```
@Configuration
public class InetConfig {
    @Bean
    public String hostname() {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    }
}
```